# Can i use the --testparam options when executing tests within Visual Studio when i installed Nunit3 TestAdapter

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, nunit-3.0, vstest

When debugging my tests I cant read any --testparam from the commandline when running tests within visual studio using the test explorer.

When i run the test from the commandline using Nunit-console.. with the argument --testparam:env:acc my code retrieves the value and runs accordingly.

My understanding was that if i install the Nunit3.testadapter it would use the Nunit testadapter when running tests in visual studio and when i go the the projects properties and on the tab debug insert command-line arguments it would run similarly.

I ran using the command-line and from within visual studio.

```
var env = TestContext.Parameters.Get("Env");
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"Config\\settings.{env}.json", optional: false)
    .Build();
return configuration;
```

expect env to be acc when i put --testparam:Env=acc

[Screenshot of arguments parsed from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpZaM.png)